# Counter widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create some counter widget with increment and dicrement buttons and count number between them.
Is it possible to create counter with design:

[image]

Here is what I have now:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          _createIncrementDicrementButton(Icons.remove, () => _dicrement()),
          Text(_currentCount.toString()),
          _createIncrementDicrementButton(Icons.add, () => _increment()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _increment() {
    setState(() {
      _currentCount++;
      _counterCallback(_currentCount);
    });
  }

  void _dicrement() {
    setState(() {
      if (_currentCount > 1) {
        _currentCount--;
        _counterCallback(_currentCount);
      }
    });
  }

  Widget _createIncrementDicrementButton(IconData icon, Function onPressed) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 24.0, minHeight: 24.0),
      onPressed: onPressed,
      elevation: 2.0,
      fillColor: LightGreyColor,
      child: Icon(
        icon,
        color: BlackColor,
        size: 12.0,
      ),
      shape: CircleBorder(),
    );
  }
```

The problem is that I can't put borderRadius to container, it gives me an error.
Thanks!

Comment: can you please show which line of code is throwing error? or how u r trying to add border radius?

Comment: Hi @JohnyDeph try using a plugin such as https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_counter

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've just solved the problem! My mistake was in container's color which conflicted with boxDecoration, I'll post full answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To the next searchers! Full code of counter:

```
class CounterView extends StatefulWidget {
  final int initNumber;
  final Function(int) counterCallback;
  final Function increaseCallback;
  final Function decreaseCallback;
  final int minNumber;
  CounterView({this.initNumber, this.counterCallback, this.increaseCallback, this.decreaseCallback, this.minNumber});
  @override
  _CounterViewState createState() => _CounterViewState();
}

class _CounterViewState extends State<CounterView> {
  int _currentCount;
  Function _counterCallback;
  Function _increaseCallback;
  Function _decreaseCallback;
  int _minNumber;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentCount = widget.initNumber ?? 1;
    _counterCallback = widget.counterCallback ?? (int number) {};
    _increaseCallback = widget.increaseCallback ?? () {};
    _decreaseCallback = widget.decreaseCallback ?? () {};
    _minNumber = widget.minNumber ?? 0;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(BorderRadiusMedium),
         color: LightGreyColor,
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          _createIncrementDicrementButton(Icons.remove, () => _dicrement()),
          Text(_currentCount.toString()),
          _createIncrementDicrementButton(Icons.add, () => _increment()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _increment() {
    setState(() {
      _currentCount++;
      _counterCallback(_currentCount);
      _increaseCallback();
    });
  }

  void _dicrement() {
    setState(() {
      if (_currentCount > minNumber) {
        _currentCount--;
        _counterCallback(_currentCount);
        _decreaseCallback();
      }
    });
  }

  Widget _createIncrementDicrementButton(IconData icon, Function onPressed) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 32.0, minHeight: 32.0),
      onPressed: onPressed,
      elevation: 2.0,
      fillColor: LightGreyColor,
      child: Icon(
        icon,
        color: BlackColor,
        size: 12.0,
      ),
      shape: CircleBorder(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is what I have now:
[image]

Comment: Where do I get the BorderRadiumMedium and PaddingMedium references from?

Comment: They are static, in my case: const BorderRadiusMicro = 5.0;
const BorderRadiusSmall = 10.0;
const BorderRadiusMedium = 15.0;
const BorderRadiusLarge = 20.0;

const PaddingSmall = 10.0;
const PaddingMedium = 15.0;
const PaddingLarge = 20.0;

Comment: Is that ok?))))